# ExtJS 6 - Update proxy store and keep the current grid state

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have a tree grid binded to a proxy store which needs to keep updated by calling a webservice every X seconds. This store have N records and I need to update all of them (for example this records are tasks executions and I need to update the progress).

How can I "reload" this grid without loosing the expanded branches? It seems to be like the store is been flushed and refilled, it would be good if the store is intelligent enough to add the new records and update the previous ones, is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I faced the same issue. I solved it with sending an additional parameter, when reloading the store, which told the back-end which of the nodes are currently expanded. Then I included the data of the expanded nodes in the response, because I only needed to reload the expanded nodes (the not expanded ones are not visible and will be loaded on expand).

So in your case you could append and event handler to the store "beforeload" event which would append the info about the expanded nodes to the request. Then on load event expand the nodes that were expanded.

So, before load save the nodes:

```
store.on("beforeload", function(store, operation) {
    var root = store.getRoot(),
        saveExpandedNodesIds = function(node) {
            if (node.childNodes) {
                Ext.Array.each(node.childNodes, function(rec){ 
                    if (rec.get('expanded')) {
                        // save to tree object
                        tree.expandedNodes[]= rec.get('id');
                        saveExpandedNodesIds(rec);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    saveExpandedNodesIds(root);
});
```

And on load restore the expanded state

```
store.on("load", function() {
                fn: function(store) {
                    /**
                     * If tree has expanded nodes, expand them after load
                     */
                    if(tree.expandedNodes > 0) {
                        while(tree.expandedNodes.length > 0) {
                            var item = tree.expandedNodes.shift();
                            if (store.getById(item) !== null) {
                                store.getById(item).expand();
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                }
        });
```

I can write a snippet later if you like.

Comment: Yes! It seems to be a nice approach, I'm not going to mark it as answer until I try it, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried it yet? Please mark as answer if it is ok.

Comment: Yes, it worked like a charm! Thank you very much! (Please edit your post in the first block you have written "funciton" instead of "function").

Comment: Why sending the Ids to the back-end and not saving them on the store instance for example?